# Intellij IDEA 12 deadlock and lost changes

Tags: intellij-idea

As you are working on the IDE, suddenly it has no reaction, the whole IDE become inactive and can not operate on it, but with high CPU usage, If you kill the process from Windows Task Manager, after it launched, all modified lost since your last edit. This problem occurs every now and then.

My environments:
Windows 7, Intel i7, 16GB RAM, IDEA 12.1.6 with auto save enabled.

Did anyone come across this problem before, it's to bad as my changes lost and i have to rewrite it after restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to upgrade to v12.1.6 as 12.1.5 had a major bug in it that was [fixed in 12.1.6](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+12.1+129.1359+Release+Notes). The bug prevented compiling of code in some circumstances. 12.1.6 was released only a few days after 12.1.5. That may not be the cause of your issue, but is still good advice.

Other than that, the 12.1.x line has been very stable. I think your issue is an isolated case as I have not seen any mention of it in the [IntelliJ IDEA forums](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/ideacommunity?view=discussions&start=0) or here. Often times, such deadlocks are caused by third party plug-ins. Take a look in the logs (*Help > Show Log*) to see if it has any information that explains the hang. Also, if IDEA becomes non responsive, it automatically logs thread dumps in the log directory. Those may have some information.

If you experience the issue again, you may want to disable any third-party plug-ins to see if that resolves it. If it happens frequently, you can take a CPU Snapshot as described in [this document](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-192) and submit it to the JetBrains.

Lastly, I recommend you tweak the following setting: *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > General > Save files automatically if application is idle for x sec."* Set it to 15 or 30 seconds. (You don't want to go too low). This will help reduce any loss of work in the event of a hang (which after 10 years of daily IDEA use I can attest to as being very rare.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail answer, I just take your suggestion that disable some plugins i didn't use(i can't disable all because i have to work), and set "Save files automatically if application is idle for 15 sec.", let's see what happen in a few days.